# multithreading not working

Tags: python, multithreading, gpio

@KSFT

currently frustrated by my inability to either decipher the formatting on stackoverflow OR make a simple python script work...

whats wrong here?

the program prompts for input to determine the value of dwell but it does not result in an led turning on.

```
import threading
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
frequency = 0.05
dwell = 0.01


def get_input():
    while True:
        dwell=raw_input("Brightness: ")

input_thread=threading.Thread(target=get_input())
input_thread.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(frequency)
        GPIO.output(7, 1)
        time.sleep(dwell)
        GPIO.output(7, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
input_thread=threading.Thread(target=get_input())
```

is wrong!

```
input_thread=threading.Thread(target=get_input)
```

is right!

[threading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qggN1.png)

```
class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})
```

If you want to give arg to get_input ,you need to give it throw args and kwargs.

Example:

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/python
 2 #current's number of threads
 3 import threading
 4 import time
 5 
 6 def worker():
 7     print "test"
 8     time.sleep(1)
 9 
 10 for i in xrange(5):
 11     t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
 12     t.start()
 13 
 14 print "current has %d threads" % (threading.activeCount() - 1)
```

target=worker().
[image: target=worker()]

target=worker.
[image: target=worker]

Comment: that part was working.

What is happening is get_input is being called and looping around as one would expect, however the while loop in which the control of the light takes place does not seem to be executing

Comment: target just need an object, so there is no ().

Comment: can you provide me with an example using the code i have posted?

Comment: target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method. Defaults to None, meaning nothing is called.[doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Comment: @ByronHill Ah, I see the mistake was just a typo when you were copying my answer.